# Sorting the splunk timechart table with the values in descending order based on a row's values in the timechart table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

This is my splunk query

```
index=xxxxx "searchTerm")|rex "someterm(?<errortype>)" | timechart count by
errortype span ="1w" | addcoltotals labelfield=total | fillnullvalue=TOTAL|fileds - abc,def,total
```

I am adding the total count of the errors over a week  in another column named TOTAL as depicted in table below.Here A... B... are error names in alphabetical order, the values are total number of errors that occured on that day for that errortype

```
_time       A....   A....   C....   D....   E....

2021-08-25  11      22      05      23      89  
2021-08-26  15      45      45      13      39  
2021-08-27  34      05      55      33      85
2021-08-28  56      08      65      53      09
2021-08-29  01      06      95      36      01
TOTAL       117     86      265     158     223
```

I want these sorted by value in TOTAL row in descending order like

```
265 223 158 117 86
```

But i am always getting this in alphabetical order of the errortype like

```
A... A... B...
```

how can i improve this query to get the sorted result like i want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, transpose the results so the TOTAL field is a column instead of the row.  Then sort on TOTAL and transpose the results back.  Here's a run-anywhere example:

```
index=_internal 
| timechart span="5m" count by component  
| addcoltotals labelfield=_time label="TOTAL"
| transpose header_field="_time" 0
| sort - TOTAL
| transpose header_field="column" 0
| rename column as _time
```

Comment: This is awesome, but shockingly complicated for something that should be an obvious requirement of charting. This worked for me, but only with column charting (not for line charts) -- I don't know why that would make a difference.